passing tds_version to sqlalchemy in the connection string
I need to pass tds_version=7.0 to my connection string so that pymssql will use the correct tds version.
I've just not been able to include it in the mssql+pymssql://user:pass@host/database?charset=utf8 format. If I try to add it (&tds_version=7.0) it ends up throwing an error for an invalid parameter.
Is there a better way that keeps the format above?

I dunno, simply appending &tds_version=7.0 works for me. Please [edit] your question to include the complete stack trace.

well this is awkward. I must've typed something wrong because it indeed works now. Your answer did stop me from barking up the wrong tree for another few hours of my life so thank you.
